# Table CSS selector is applying to whole page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to customise my wordpress theme and have given a column a class of
betting-tips-column.

I'm trying to change the p & h4 tags from white to black within this column using:

```
.betting-tips-column h4, p, body p{
color:black!important;
border-radius:8px;
}
```

However, it's affecting the whole page, not just the text within the column.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.betting-tips-column h4,
.betting-tips-column p {
  color: black !important;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to basically nest all child elements inside their parents and further separate them by commas.

If you don't do the same then the css will be applied to all the `p` tags throughout your document.

Change it to the following:

```
.betting-tips-column h4, .betting-tips-column p {
  color: black!important;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To style `<p>` and `<h4>` tags in a container with class `.betting-tips-column` you can use the following CSS code:

```
.betting-tips-column h4, 
.betting-tips-column p {
    color:black!important;
    border-radius:8px;
}
```

**Why your CSS doesn't work?**

You only prefix the `<h4>` tag with your column class `.betting-tips-column`.

***You defined the following rules:***

- `p` matches all `<p>` tags on the whole site.
- `body p` matches all `<p>` tags in all `<body>` tags (should be only one `<body>` tag).
- `.betting-tips-column h4` matches all `<h4>` tags in container with class `.betting-tips-column`

**Hint:** The rule `p` and `body p` makes no sense because they affect both nearly the same `<p>` tags.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks very much. 

Could you offer a quick explanation as to why mine wasn't working. Just poor syntax?

Comment: Yes you need to prefix the `h4` and `p` with your column column name. `p` matches all `<p>` tags on the site. `body p` matches all `<p>` tags in `<body>` tags. `.betting-tips-column p` matches all `<p>` tags in container with class `.betting-tips-column`.